# SOLVED: Where Dancer2 tutorial script is looking for css/stype.css file?

Tags: css, perl, dancer

SOLVED: magically on restart `public\css\style.css` was picked up and rendered in web browser (no changes to project files was made)

download [project files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17UlDq8a8UzCzZ-Dhu8w9rmGylnFVQ-PG)

I have followed [Dancer2::Tutorial](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Tutorial) instruction and got it working.

```
OS: Windows 10
Perl: Strawberry perl v5.30.2
```

But I can not figure out where `css/style.css` should be placed to be used with the script.

I have tried following location:

```
 {script_location}\css\style.css
 {script_location}\public\css\style.css
```

Template `view\layouts\main.tt` defines `<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="[% css_url %]">` as location of the `style.css` file.

The code defines `$tokens->{'css_url'} = request->base . 'css/style.css';` as location of `style.css` file.

Rendered HTML code has `<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="http://localhost:3000/css/style.css">` in the header.

And still CSS style defined in `style.css` does not produce expected result.

```
.intro {
     background-color: #555;
}
```

For a test I have defined in `view\show_entries.tt` template

```
<dev class="intro">This line should have different background color</dev>
```

What is proper location [Dancer2::Tutorial](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Tutorial) for `style.css` file?

NOTE: created database file `dancer.db` was not found in 'project' directory, but it was found in temporary directory `%TEMP%` instead.

NOTE: if style defined inside `<head></head>` it produces expected result

```
<head>
    <style>
       .intro {
           background-color: #555;
       }
    </style>
</head>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: @simbabque -- Top of my post states `OS: Windows 10`.

Comment: Sorry, it's early morning here. When you load the page, does it actually load the CSS file? Look at your developer tools with F12 and go to the network tab, then reload the page please. Are there 404 errors? Try shift-reloading to clear the browser's CSS cache.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and include a screenshot of the full request, or copy/paste it in. I think the path is wrong.

Comment: Yes, or copy the full request. I would like to see what it is requesting.

Comment: @simbabque -- the line `Hey there...` is `<div class="intro">Hey there...</div>` block which should have different background color.

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with your settings. If that file is in the `public/css` folder it should work. Can you show your file, and also what the Dancer log shows? How do you run the app? Is there anything extra in the psgi file?

Comment: @simbabque -- I followed tutorial and copy/pasted file content from tutorial. The tutorial does not explain well where what files should be located. No further alternation was made to content of the code, I've attempted to modify `view\show_entries.tt` to add `div` block so that `style.css` was utilized. The app run with `perl first-app.pl` command. The code specifies `set 'logger'       => 'console'; set 'log'          => 'debug';` -- all output goes to console.

Comment: @simbabque -  In the console I see `perl\Dancer\MyFirst-App>perl first-app.pl
>> Dancer2 v0.300000 server 15264 listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210454/discussion-between-simbabque-and-polar-bear).